# Как вывести определенне данные из бд с помощью php?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!Я хочу на сайте сделать "мой профиль",чтобы в нем у каждого пользователя отражались: имя,аватар,кол-во побед и кол-во игр.Как сделать так,чтобы у каждого пользователя выходились эти данные? Если можно,с пояснением

Comment: http://komotoz.ru/uroki/php/mysql_osnovy.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести определенные данные о пользователе из БД mysql?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787630/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно что вам известно, а что не известно, чего именно вы не можете понять. Если брать во внимание формулировку вашего вопроса, можно предположить что с php и mysql вы только знакомитесь, так что опишу один вариант механизма авторизации и личного профиля.

Вам нужно:

- **База данных с таблицей пользователей**. В этой таблице есть колонки соответствующие тем атрибутам пользователя, которые вы хотите показывать (имя, наименование файла аватара,кол-во побед и т.д.)
- В этой же таблице создать **колонки для "логина" и "пароля"**. Причем пароль желательно держать в зашифрованном виде (хотя бы обычный md5-хеш), так же можно создать колонку для некоего уникального ID'а (об этом позже)
- **Страница с формой логина**, с полями для ввода логина, пароля и кнопка "войти". Эти данные, после нажатия на кнопку "войти" будут отправляться скрипту, а скрипт будет делать следующее: найдет в базе данных запись у которой логин равен введенному логину, а пароль равен введенному и зашифрованному паролю. Если такая запись в БД найдена, скрипт запишет в колонку уникального ID'а этой записи некий ключ (случайный номер), и затем поместит его же в сессию (сессию можете воспринимать как некий контейнер в который можно помещать различные значения, и которые будут доступны для ваших скриптов пока клиент не закроет браузер). После того, как это произойдет, юзер будет считаться залогиненым, и теперь можно показывать юзеру те страницы, которые доступны только для залогиненых участников.
- **Скрипт, показывающий страницы доступные только для авторизованных, ПРОВЕРЯЕТ - залогинен ли юзер**. Это вы можете делать обращаясь к бд, находя ту запись у которой ID равен тому что сейчас в сессии. Если такая запись найдеа - значит все ок. Если нет - пользователь не авторизован (перенаправляете его на какую-то общедоступную страницу или выводите сообщение о нехватке доступа)
- **На странице профиля** вы так же обращаетесь к БД, извлекая запись  соответствующую ID'у в сессии и получаете необходимые данные. Эти данные вы и выводите.

Не знаю какую ОС вы используете, и на чем тестируете ваши разработки. Если Windows - советую OpenServer. Он включает все необходимое для работы веб-приложений локально (php, mysql и многое другое), при этом вам ничего не нужно будет конфигурировать. В нем так же есть PhpMyAdmin, для работы с базой данных (по сути веб-приложение на php для управления бд), но для удобства советую использовать, например, Navicat.

В общем, разумеется, если вы только знакомитесь с этой темой, то этот ответ не покроет все ваши вопросы (я описал только теоретическую часть), но теперь у вас, наверное, есть понимание в какою сторону идти как рассуждать. Пишите в комментарии, если что-то не ясно.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ!У меня логин происходит через steam-авторизацию.Как мне идентифицировать пользователя,чтобы вывести определенные данные о нем из бд?
Если нужно - код https://pastebin.com/dGJG4T3L

Comment: Не знаю как там со стимом, но предполагаю что аналогично тому как это происходит при авторизации через другие соц-сети. То есть при успешной авторизации вы получаете некий ID юзера соцсети (в данном случае стима), затем ищите в БД (в таблице юзеров) соотв. запись, у которой steam_id равен тому что был получен. Если не находите - создаете. Затем обновляете информацию записи (в бд вписываете имя, аватар и тд) что получили из стима и авторизуете данного юзера в своей системе (пишете в сессию свой ключ)..

Comment: У меня имеется уже бд.Мне нужно создать "мой профиль",чтобы для каждого пользователя выводились свои данные:Никнейм,имя,возраст и т.п.Как можно вывести данные о пользователе ему на экран?

Comment: Когда пользователь авторизуется в первый раз, у вас в системе создается пользователь? В базу что-то пишется? Вас интересует как извлечь данные из БД, или как именно показать то, что вы извлекли?

Comment: Когда авторизуется новый пользователь - создается его id(порядковый номер),пишется его steamid,никнейм и ссылка на аватар.Меня интересует как сделать так,чтобы пользователь,нажавший кнопку "мой профиль",увидел определенные данные о себе

Comment: Создаете php срикпт, который будет выводить этот самый профиль. Обычный php файл. Кнопка "мой профиль" ведет на него. Этот скрипт должен проверить, авторизован ли пользователь в вашей системе (есть ли в сессии ID и есть ли такой ID в базе). Если есть - извлекаете из базы данные (SELECT * FROM users WHERE какой_то_ID = ВАШ_ID_ИЗ_СЕССИИ), эти данные выводите на странице.

Comment: "Если есть - извлекаете из базы данные (SELECT * FROM users WHERE какой_то_ID = ВАШ_ID_ИЗ_СЕССИИ), эти данные выводите на странице".Если я правильно понял,то будет так: (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $_SESSION(id)) ?

Comment: Я не знаю какая структура вашей базы, какие поля у таблицы и что вы записываете в сессию. $_SESSION - это массив, соответственно к его ключам надо обращаться так - $_SESSION['наименование_ключа']. В вашем коде есть проверка на steamid, если в базу он пишется - можете использовать его для проверки авторизации, а не какой-то свой внутренний ID. По сути разницы особой нет.

Comment: Спасибо.Пойду ставить